# Dependent Drop-downs using html and Flask

Tags: html, flask, dropdown, html-select

How do I make dependent drop-downs in html using Flask?

I have four drop-downs. I basically want that the options in the second drop-down comes according to what was selected in the first drop-down. I have made the drop-downs in HTML styled using CSS and integrated with Flask.

I couldn't find anything on the internet, which could help me. Please let me know if I need to share my code. Below is my code

Flask

```
from flask import render_template,request,redirect,url_for,Flask
from FlaskWebProject3 import app


@app.route('/')

@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    proglist = ["Btech","MBATech","Btech_Integrated","Mtech"]


    return render_template('UI2.html', proglist=proglist)

@app.route("/hello", methods = ['POST'])
def hello():
    select = request.form.get('val')
    select2 = request.form.get('val2')
    select3 = request.form.get('val3')
    select4 = request.form.get('val4')
    final = str(select)+" "+str(select2)+" "+str(select3)+" "+str(select4)
    if "None" in final:
        return "Please select some option in all dropdowns"
    else:
        return final
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale =1.0">
    <title>Select Options</title>
   <style>
    body {
        background: url("F:/Meethi Folder/COLLEGE/COMPETITIONS/Sidh Competition/nmims_logo.png");
        background-position:515px 330px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:15%;
         }

    h2 {
     color: black;
       }

    .wrapper{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .button{
        position:absolute;
        left:570px;
        background-color:#A9A9A9;
        font-size: 30px;
        top:35%;
    }   

    form{
        display:inline-block
    }

    .ex
    {
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    border:outset;
    }

    select
     {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:16px;
    }
    .ey
    {
     display:inline-block;
    padding:40px;
     } 

    .gap{
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    }

   </style>
  </head>

<body>

<div class = "ex">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('hello')}}">

        <h2> Choose The Programme:</h2>
        <select name="val" method="GET" action="/">
            <option value="None" selected>Select Programme</option>
            {% for x in proglist %}
            <option value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>


        <h2> Choose The Course:</h2>
        <select name="val2">
            <option value="None" selected>Select Course</option>
            <option value="CS">CS</option>
            <option value="DS">DS</option>
            <option value="EXTC">EXTC</option>
            <option value="civil">civil</option>
            <option value="mechanical">mechanical</option>
        </select>

        <h2> Choose The Year:</h2>
        <select name="val3">
            <option value="None">Select Year</option>
            <option value="First_Year">First Year</option>
            <option value="Second_Year">Second Year</option>
            <option value="Third_Year">Third Year</option>
            <option value="Fourth_Year">Fourth Year</option>
            <option value="Fifth_Year">Fifth Year</option>
            <option value="Sixth_Year">Sixth Year</option>
        </select>

        <h2> Choose The Hour:</h2>
        <select name="val4">
            <option value="None">Select Time Slot</option>
            <option value="8:00am">8:00 am</option>
            <option value="9:00am">9:00 am</option>
            <option value="10:00am">10:00 am</option>
            <option value="11:00am">11:00 am</option>
            <option value="12:00pm">12:00 pm</option>
            <option value="1:00pm">1:00 pm</option>
            <option value="2:00pm">2:00 pm</option>
            <option value="3:00pm">3:00 pm</option>
            <option value="4:00pm">4:00 pm</option>
            <option value="5:00pm">5:00 pm</option>
        </select>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <button class="button" type="submit">Start</button>
        </div>
    </form>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to share your code.

Comment: @jmargolisvt please see the edit

Comment: You should use `flask_wtf` package. You can read more about [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/crash_course.html).  [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_wtf.htm) is a code sample that should help you figure out how to use the package.